# Socket timeout when writing large dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I'm running Apache Spark on my local laptop. 
*Apache Spark 3.3.1 | 16 GB RAM | 8-core CPU.*

I have a dataframe containing data on Twitter-users, the data is retrieved from a bunch of JSON-files on my local machine. The dataframe has approx. 550,000 rows and three columns, two datatypes are strings and one is of datatype long. I first cleaned & transformed the dataframe and now I need to use the data elsewhere, so I want to write it to a CSV first.

I tried to do this

```
df.write.options(header=True).mode('overwrite').csv('tweets.csv')
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11952/106748238.py in <module>
----> 1 twitter_df.write.options(header=True).mode('overwrite').csv('test.csv')

C:\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
   1238             lineSep=lineSep,
   1239         )
-> 1240         self._jwrite.csv(path)
   1241 
   1242     def orc(

C:\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

C:\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    188     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189         try:
--> 190             return f(*a, **kw)
    191         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\Spark\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o455.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:851)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 103) (LAPTOP-CJHDAJKQ.mshome.net executor driver): java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:325)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:272)
```

**Image of first three rows:**
[screenshot dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dET8t.png)

**Code to reproduce first three rows:**

```
data=[("132857510","assistant coach","Retail, Sales and Food Jobs"),
("173972328","director security","Other Jobs"),
("3076169579","social worker","['Healthcare Jobs', 'Healthcare Jobs']")]
schema = StructType([\
    StructField("user_id",StringType(),True),\
    StructField("jobs",StringType(),True),\
    StructField("sector",StringType(),True)\
])
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema )
df.show()
```

**So far I tried:**

1. I tried setting a config [('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval','3600s'),  ('spark.network.timeout','3601s')]. This did not change the error.
2. I tried bumping up the memory (different configurations) [('spark.executor.memory','8g'),  ('spark.driver.memory','4g')]. Still got the error.
3. I tried converting the Pyspark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe (silly me)
4. I tried partitioning by the first two digits of a user's ID.
5. I tried Parquet instead of CSV
6. I tried everything I could find on SO so far.